# how to hide button on particular cell of tablview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to hide button on some cell of `UITableView` , but I am not able to find what was I did wrong , some cell of my `UITableView` have both text and button and some cell have only text with single line or multiple line. I want to show button  on some cell of `UITableView`. I did this code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      NSString *cellidentifier= @"cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton *  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, 100, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openNewPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell addSubview:button];

    if(indexPath.row ==0)
    {


        cell.textLabel.attributedText = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
     if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {


    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dataArray objectAtIndex:1]] placeholderImage:nil];
    cell.imageView.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);
    }
    if(indexPath.row ==2)
    {


        cell.textLabel.attributedText = [dataArray objectAtIndex:2];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    if(indexPath.row ==3)
    {

        cell.textLabel.attributedText = [dataArray objectAtIndex:3];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    if(indexPath.row ==4)
    {

        cell.textLabel.attributedText = [dataArray objectAtIndex:4];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


    }
      if( indexPath.row == 5)
     {

        cell.textLabel.attributedText =[dataArray objectAtIndex:5];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    }


      if(indexPath.row == 6)

     {
        //[button setHidden:YES];
         cell.textLabel.attributedText = [dataArray objectAtIndex:6];
         cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
         cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
         cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    }
    if ( indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 5)
    {
        [button setHidden:NO];
    }
    else {
        [button setHidden:YES];
    }
      return cell;
    }
```

But this code will add button on 6th and  5th cell also on 2nd and 3rd cell also , I want button only 6th and 5th cell.

Comment: Step 1: Be polite and make sure you present your code in a well formatted manner.

Comment: Access your button using tag and then use set "hidden" property to YES.

Comment: @WasimSafdar do not use tags for this

Comment: @Simon, she is assigning tag to button "button.tag = indexPath.row".

Comment: I think, he get better answer from @Cristian.

Comment: nop i tried that also but it will put button on other cell also like 2nd & 3rd cell also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't add a button as `[cell addSubView: button]` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. dequeReusableCellForIndexPath asks the `tableView` for a cell. The `tableView` creates one if it doesn't have any or passes an old one. If you receive and old one, then I may already have a button. If you add another one, you will end up with a stack of buttons.

You can achieve what you want in two ways:
You can create your cell in the `storyboard`, for example, add the button and create an outlet in a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. Then you can hide or unhide the button according to what cell is.

The other way, if buttons are too different, you can create two cells in the storyboard with different identifiers, for example "cellWithButton" and "cellWithoutButton".

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row < 5) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellWithoutButton"];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellWithButton"];
    }

    // Do the rest of your configuration

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i tired this one also but it add button on cell 2nd and 3rd also with cell 6th and 5th

Comment: let me post a new comment

Comment: let me try this @CristianPena

Comment: thanks thanks thanks @CristianPena you save me its work fantastic thanksss

Answer (score 0):

I think You Should Try

adding button at start just add it later.
like,

```
if ( indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 5)
{
   [cell addSubview:button];
}
else {
   [button removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do by

```
UIButton *  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];// or UIButtonTypeCustom 
button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, 100, 30);
[button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(openNewPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
button.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

if(indexPath.row==0)
{
     button.hidden = YES;
}
else if(indexPath.row==1){
     button.hidden = YES;
}
else if(indexPath.row==2){
     button.hidden = YES;
}
else if(indexPath.row==3){
     button.hidden = YES;
}
else if(indexPath.row==4){
     button.hidden = YES;
}
else if(indexPath.row==5 || indexPath.row==6){
     button.hidden = NO;
}
```

OR else

```
UIButton *  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; // or UIButtonTypeCustom 
button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, 100, 30);
[button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(openNewPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
button.tag = indexPath.row;

if(indexPath.row==0)
{

}
else if(indexPath.row==1){

}
else if(indexPath.row==2){

}
else if(indexPath.row==3){

}
else if(indexPath.row==4){

}
else if(indexPath.row==5 || indexPath.row==6){
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: not working this dont know why,  i was did  your first code yesterday but it will put that button on its corresponding or  multiply number other cell

Comment: Yesterday did you try my answer?I posted my answer just now iAsmi.

Comment: i mean i was tried out this from yesterday from various and  way same as you gave right now its not working dn't know why @user3182143

Comment: I would say you have not tried any of the code who have answered here.

Comment: Try each answer.It they give shortly customize the code according to your code.First of all you must have patience.You can bring the solution easily.You can.

Comment: yes let me try all , and i did this from yesterday for only two buttons @user3182143

Comment: Be Cool:-)Don't be nervous.You can get it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UIButton *  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];// or UIButtonTypeCustom 
button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, 100, 30);
[button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(openNewPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
button.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

if(indexPath.row==5 || indexPath.row==6){
     button.hidden = NO;
}
else {
     button.hidden = YES;
}
```

It will eliminate your code and readable too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIButton *  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, 100, 30);
  [button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openNewPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
  button.tag = indexPath.row;
  //add here 
  button.hidden==YES;
  [cell addSubview:button];

  and after write this condition 
  if ( indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 5)
   {
  [button setHidden:NO];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make [cell addSubview:button] in 6th and 5th cell